# How to synchronize data from windows mobile 6 with pc?

Tags: windows, linux, sync, windows-mobile

I would like to use something like dropbox. however dropbox does not support windows mobile. is there any freeware application that allows that?

Comment: What platform are we talking about for PC?

Comment: @RecNes windows xp or ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ehow.com/how_6928449_sync-phone-windows-7.html

#### Initial Setup:

1. Connect the phone to the PC using the USB sync cable. WMDC will start the synchronization process as soon as the phone is connected to your PC.
2. Click "Set up your device" on your PC in the open WMDC window.
3. Click the checkboxes next to the data that you want to sync. Data options showing are: Contacts; Calendar; Email; Tasks; Notes; Mobile Favorites. Clear any box that you do not want synchronized and click "Next."
4. Enter a name for your phone in the "Device Name" box. Uncheck the shortcut check box if you do not want a shortcut to WMDC on your desktop.
5. Click "Set Up" to start synchronizing. You will be prompted when the synchronization has been completed.

#### Synchronizing after the initial setup:

1. Connect the phone to the PC.
2. Start synchronizing from your phone by clicking "Start > ActiveSync > Sync."
3. Start synchronizing from your PC in the Windows Mobile Device Center by clicking "Sync."

Read more: How to Sync a Phone in Windows 7: http://www.ehow.com/how_6928449_sync-phone-windows-7.html#ixzz1iH1huWI2

Comment: [It would be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link only for future reference.

Comment: i did, can you explain why you posted that link? what windows mobile 7 has to do with anything?

Comment: even if it did work (and it doesn't) that is not what I want. you don't connect to dropbox by usb.